# Static table view outside UITableViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch

After the new Xcode update, my app doesn't validate and shows this error:

> static table views are only valid when embedded in UITableViewController instances

Any chances to solve easily?

Comment: Depends on why you're using a UIViewController subclass instead of a UITableViewController.

Comment: Because I need other elements inside the view which doesn't belong to a UITableViewController

Comment: Experiencing the same issue here. Just upgraded (or downgraded, as it seems, so far) to Xcode 5.1 and i have the same issue. I have a bunch of static cells in a UITableViewController subclass inside my UISplitViewController.

Comment: Started happening for me too after the upgrade. I do have some view controllers constructed with static cells, it isn't ideal but it was working fine before.

Comment: You don't need to use UITableViewController. You get this error if you have Static table view cells in your UiTableView, so I think one easy solution is if you need the cells, don't leave it static. Just add tableview delegate and datasource and dummy UITableViewDelegate methods

Comment: I can't think of a good reason why you can't have static table views in a UITableView.

Comment: Or refactor to use Dynamic Prototypes instead of Static Cells if possible.

Answer (score 354):

The only way to get a static UITableView along with other controls on the same screen is to use a Container View. Follow this way, it works perfectly:

1. Drag a ViewController onto your storyboard.
2. Drag a TableViewController onto your storyboard.
3. Next Drag a Container view to your ViewController and size it about the size you want (smaller than the view) -> when you drag the container view it will create a segue and another view. Remove that segue and view.
4. Then finally ctrl click in your container and drag to your new TableViewContoller. Select Embed.
5. Style your TableView the way you want -> including static cells.

This answer was already found and given here: G.Huebner -> http://web.archive.org/web/20140928102504/http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/111800-static-table-view-cells-only-work-in-a-uitableviewcontroller.html

Comment: Where to take outlet or action? In `UIViewController` or should I have to take `UITableViewController`.

Comment: @Bhavin Ramani: Since it is an UITableViewController in the container I suggest take exactly that class / subclass for holding your IBOutlets.

Comment: I guess the whole "static cells" idea is implemented in a way that depends on some internal functionality of `UITableViewController`.

Comment: Thank you for this. Can confirm it works in Xcode 8.3.1.

Comment: Just awesome! I was looking for this solution for awhile now.

Comment: This even works when you need `prefersLargeTitles`with static cells in iOS 11

Answer (score 9):

A static UITableView must be in a UITableViewController. So you will have place the table in UITableViewController and then add it as childView to the MainViewController.

You can refer
https://iphoneidoit.blogspot.in/2013/10/static-uitableview-in-uiviewcontroller.html

Comment: There were many ways around this before, (such as retaining the cell), but now its an error regardless. I think the question is suggesting if there is a way to suppress the error.

Comment: Yeah it was. Unfortunately, I ended up solving the problem using a non-static tableView

Comment: Yikes. The amount of re-work it would require to convert to not static due to all the `IBOutlet`s in my view controller file is too much, and IMO it's unacceptable for an update to break this with no warning or note of this in the change log (ergo I assume it's still perfectly valid on paper to have a `UITableViewController` with static cells inside a `UISplitViewContoller`. I have contacted Apple's developer support and only received a generically not-so-helpful email response linking me to the forums. I suppose I will try there and see if anyone else is having the same problems post-update.

Answer (score 4):

I think what you are doing is you are first dragging the ViewController on the storyboard and then dragging the tableView on the ViewController. In this way you can't use the Static table cells. Instead of this what you should have done is Drag the TableViewController on the main storyboard instead of a ViewController and then select the static cells. In this way you can be able to work on static cells and can use any elements on static cells.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you are really using a static tableView, you should consider copy/past everything to a ScrollView or StackView.