# how to set values in a uitableviewcontroller embedded in uicontainerview inside uiviewcontroller

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uicontainerview

I'm trying to create a viewcontroller that has an image and a uitableviewcontroller with static cells, I've read this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22364230/static-table-view-outside-uitableviewcontroller) that said the only possible way to achieve that is creating a container view with a segue that embeds a uitableviewcontroller like so:
[image]

I can't figure out how to assign values from mixViewController to the tableViewController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the explanation:
http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-tutorials/111816-using-static-table-views-in-ios-6-using-embed-segues.html

here is a Git project to reference:
https://github.com/DuncanMC/test