# Using Static UITableViewCells in a UIViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have a functional tab-bar based application with three tabs and each tab containing a `UITableView`.

The first and second tabs are set to use `Dynamic Cells`.

Due to wanting to bring `iAds` to my app, I have converted my `UITableViewControllers` of the first and second tab to a `UIViewController` with an embedded `UITableView` and it works really well.

However, with the third tab, which uses `Static Cells` (like an `In-App-Settings`, when I do this same approach, I get an error saying `Static cells` need to be used with a `UITableViewController`.

I've been searching online and came across this question with the same approach:

[Static TableViews Outside UITableViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22364230/static-table-view-outside-uitableviewcontroller)

The accepted answer makes sense and I've tried that as well, but I'm not getting anywhere with this.

Is there a way to achieve this with the static cells, in the same as the dynamic cells?

Any guidance on this would be appreciated!

Comment: no, the easy way to have a `TableView` with `Static Cells` is by using a `UITableViewController`, and the hard way using IB is following the steps explained in the answer you are referencing.

Comment: the other option is change the table view to use dynamics cells and construct and control its behaviour (`dataSource` and `delegate`) from your code

Comment: Thanks so much for the response - it seems really complicated for simply adding in a few iAd Banners and because the rest of the app has it, it's not required in this Tab. Thanks again for the response.