# UIDatePicker issue in iOS9

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, uidatepicker

Date is hiding in `UIDatePicker` in iOS9. i am using xib.

This issue is only in xoode7(iOS9)

[image] 
    Can any one help me to solve my issue??

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think this is problem with new font San Francisco (the font is big than Helvetica ) and .xib file. 
It can be hacked around by changing the `UIDatePicker` mode right before it was displayed, and then changing it back to the desired one:

```
[myDatePicker setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime];
[myDatePicker setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDate];
```

Also try adding DatePicker programmatically.

I think its a bug in iOS 9 with new font.

Comment: adding date picker programmatically i have get date formate like this :-mm/dd/yyyy but i want dd/mm/yyyy formate. i want as per i have shown image above

Comment: You can change format as well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13952063/how-to-change-the-format-of-date-in-date-picker

Comment: Incredible. I solved the "UIDatePicker inside UITAbleViewCell" problem sometime ago (http://stackoverflow.com/a/32899795/433373), and just realized it was broken again for no apparent reason. This did the trick! Have my vote.

Comment: My date picker in ios9 has become very very small not even showing properly. I also tried to set it to UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime but not working.

Comment: Amazing and sad, all wrapped into one!  You're my hero.