# UIDatePicker selected value is hidden

Tags: ios, objective-c, uidatepicker

I'm creating a `UIDatePicker` programmatically that permits to select a date (day/month/year).

When I scroll to select inputs (day, month or year), the selected value is always hidden. Here a screenshot:

[image: UIDatePicker hidden selected value bug]

I have no idea what kind of bug it is and didn't find any solutions on Stackoverflow.

Code used:

```
CGRect datePickerFrame = CGRectMake(0, 40, self.view.frame.size.width, 216);
UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:datePickerFrame];
[self.view addSubview:datePicker];
```

This bug is occuring on `iPhone 5S iOS 9.2.1`
Programming language: `Objective-C`

Comment: can u show some code for your `UIDatePicker`?

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: try this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32717218/uidatepicker-issue-in-ios9

Answer (score 0):

Try following code for that;

```
    CGRect datePickerFrame = CGRectMake(0, 40, self.view.frame.size.width, 216);
    UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc]initWithFrame:datePickerFrame];
    datePicker.datePickerMode=UIDatePickerModeDate;
    datePicker.hidden=NO;
    datePicker.date=[NSDate date];
    [datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(LabelTitle:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.view addSubview:datePicker];

-(void)LabelTitle:(id)sender
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    dateFormat.dateStyle=NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
    NSString *str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dateFormat  stringFromDate:datePicker.date]];
    //assign text to label
    label.text=str;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just test by changing the Color Might be this issue I am not sure

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{
 UILabel *labelSelected = (UILabel*)[pickerView viewForRow:row forComponent:component];
[labelSelected setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];
}
```