# How to do Collapsible and Expandable TableviewCell in storyboard

Tags: swift, tableview, ios9.3, expandable-table

In Swift, how to do collapsible and expandable `TableviewCell` in storyboard using Disclosure Indicator as Accessory?

I have come across some documents and cocoapods library where I can collapse and expand cell using xib files. But I wanted to do everything (expand cell,collapse cell) in the storyboard not using xib files. Refer to the attached images:

Collapsed cell:

[image: Collapsed cell]

Expanded cell:

[image: Expanded cell]

How can I do this in **Swift** without using XIB files?

Appreciate the help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited the title of your question to be more consise and included the details in the body. I also formatted the pictures so that they render properly - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Please edit your question to provide any additional details that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good luck!

Comment: Adapt this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29678471/expanding-and-collapsing-uitableviewcells-with-datepicker/34703276#34703276

Comment: Are Family, Contact Info, Interest section or row?

Comment: Check this answer and sample link comments http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36826163/expandable-uitableview-cells-showing-datas/36826347#36826347