# Add sub tableview on tableview

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I've a little problem with this:

[gif animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JVIR.gif)

A tableview is added on my view to show categories and another tableview added when category selected for display subcategories. But interaction with the top cell is not recognized and I don't understand why ! If anyone as an idea to fix this problem, or another way to make those animations possible ..

Code is complicated to show but I'll try to explain clearly:

1. The main controller is `FilterViewController` inherit from `UIViewController`
2. When the "Categories" row selected, an instantiation of `CategoryFilterViewController` created and the view added to the `FilterViewController's` view.
3. On the `CategoryFilterViewController`, when a row selected, I instantiate new tableView and add it to the view.

[CategoryViewController storyboard view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KNYq.png)

A part of `FilterViewController`, variables and outlets 
You can see I used SnapKit to make some constraints programmatically

```
var contentViewCatHeightContrain: Constraint? = nil
var contentViewCatBottomContrain: Constraint? = nil

@IBOutlet weak var filterTableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var submitFilterButton: UIButton!
```

You see here, when "Categories" row selected, I run this code.

```
func displayCat(show: Bool, cell: FilterCell) {
     let cellRow = self.filterTableView.indexPathForCell(cell)!
     if(cellRow.row == 0) {
         if(self.viewModel.categoryContentsView == nil) {
             if let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("CategoryFilterView") as? CategoryFilterView {
                 self.viewModel.categoryContentsView = vc
                 self.viewModel.categoryContentsView.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, 0)
                 self.view.addSubview(self.viewModel.categoryContentsView.view)
                 self.addChildViewController(vc)
                 self.viewModel.categoryContentsView.view.snp_makeConstraints(closure: { (make) -> Void in
                     self.contentViewCatHeightContrain = make.height.equalTo(0).constraint
                     make.left.equalTo(0)
                     make.right.equalTo(0)
                     self.contentViewCatBottomContrain = make.bottom.equalTo(0).constraint
                 })
             }
         }
         self.viewModel.categoryContentsView.view.didMoveToSuperview()
         self.view.bringSubviewToFront(self.viewModel.categoryContentsView.view)
     }
}
```

And on the `CategoryViewController`, outlets:

```
@IBOutlet weak var catTableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var topCatTableView: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var subCatHeightContrain: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var subCatTableView: UITableView!
```

and when row selected:

```
func showHideTableView(show: Bool) {
    if(show) {
        self.topCatTableView.constant = -75
        self.subCatHeightContrain.constant = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height - 95
    }
    else {
        self.topCatTableView.constant = 0
        self.subCatHeightContrain.constant = 0
        self.catTableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: You definitely don't want to add another `UITableView` onto your pre-existing tableView. What I think you're looking to do is add another tableView to your containing `ViewController`'s main view.

Comment: SHOW US THE CODE !!! PLEASSSEEEE !!!

Comment: I suggest adding some more cells on the tableView instead of adding another tableView

Comment: @ZGski I do that, on the main view and not on the tableView itself.

Comment: @penatheboss Yes it's a possibility but I don't think animation can be the same of mine.

Comment: Then add a UITableView to a cell. That's your only possibility.

Comment: Have you taken a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29678471/expanding-and-collapsing-uitableviewcells-with-datepicker/32899795#32899795) StackOverflow post yet?

Comment: @penatheboss I also tried this solution, It's work too but cannot reproduce animation (or it will be hard to do), thx

Comment: @ZGski I keep this post, It can be useful, thx !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found what's wrong

The second tableView top contraint on `CategoryViewController` was not at 0 value. 
I had set clipSubviews to false on the child tableView which mean top cell are still visible but cannot handle any interactions because it was out of frame.

Thank's to everyone answered, that helped me to find a solution

Answer (score 0):

This could help you to create expandable and collapsable tableview

http://www.appcoda.com/expandable-table-view/

On didSelectedRow at index change navigation bar title and scroll your table to particular index to bring it on top.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{

    self.title = // String from your array which is displayed on cellForRowAtIndex

    let no = indexPath.row + 4 // Particular no which scroll table view up side so your selected row comes on first

    let lastIndex = NSIndexPath(forRow: no, inSection: 0)

    tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(lastIndex, atScrollPosition: .Bottom, animated: true)

}
```

Only 1 thing you have to compromise with backbutton and navigation bar tittle animation.

Backbutton, by using flag is_expandable or not you can pop view controller or collapse table.

Hope this will help you out to figure out your solution.

All the best.

Comment: I tried your way, it's work, but I have not animation I needed. But your answer helped me to find what's wrong ! So, thank you !

Comment: All the best. Happy coding.