# Second tableview in UITableViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

In my storyboard, I have a `UITableViewController` with **static** cell and 4 sections.

- Section 1 with 6 rows and 1st row height is much higher than others.
- Section 2 with 1 row.
- Section 3 with 4 rows.
- Section 4 with 1 row.

In the row of Section 4, I added into a `UITableView` (table2) with **dynamic** cell (no header, 1 section only).

So I followed some posts, and had some codes below:

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    if tableView == table2 {
        return 1
    }
    return super.numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView)
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if tableView == table2 {
        return 4
    }
    return super.tableView(tableView, numberOfRowsInSection: section)
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if tableView == table2 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(textCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomerCellView
        cell.setCustomCell()
        return cell
    }
    return super.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
}
```

When run it, it builds successfully. The default table shows correctly, but **table2** does not. table2 seemed to follow the format of the default table, so the problems are

- `table2` also shows the same header as the first header of default table, even I did not set.
- If I set the number of rows greater than 6, the app crashed in the simulator.
- I put the breakpoint at `tableView == table2`, the complier did goes into the if statement
- `table2` delegate and datasource are connected to the UITableViewController itself.

If anyone knows what problem my code has, or anyone knows how to add a second tableview in `UITableViewController`

Answer (score 1):

After a day, I figured out a way to solve this problem. Inspired by these posts:

- [Static table view outside UITableViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22364230/static-table-view-outside-uitableviewcontroller)

So instead of putting a `UITableView` in the static cell, I put a `Container View` inside of the cell (in my case, the first row of Section 4), which `embedded` to another `UITableViewController` or `UIViewController` depends on your needs. The corresponding tableview codes go to another new file. And the way to set up the new table is as usual.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to create an uiviewcontroler and add 2 table views in that view. Then you can link them to the view controller with the data source and delegate. Then add the delegate in the view controllers class. After add in the normal functions for a table view.. You can use reeuse identifyers to classify which one needed.

Best of luck, Aj

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did try this, but when I set `static cells` in `UIViewController`, there is a red error msg: "static table views are only valid when embedded in UITableViewController instances"

Comment: Did you make the data source and delegate outlets?

Comment: And add the delegate in the view controller class?

Comment: Yes, I did. And the red error msg appear immediately just after setting to static cell

Comment: Try dynamic cell, not sure though.