# Segue between Container and TableViewController, Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, segue, uistoryboardsegue, uicontainerview

I used an UITableViewController with static cells for a calculate, but the toolBar was not fix on the bottom. 
I tried with a [Container View](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25193002/5748637), I got what I was looking for, **but** I add the price on an UITextField and I can change the discount with the UISlider, both are on the IUTableViewController of the Container.

My button "calculate" is on my UIViewController, it uses information from the UITableViewController and then it displays the result in the third static cell with the UILabel "price".

Do I need to segue data at each steps?

**Thanks!!!**

[image: StoryBoard]

Comment: Please correct me if I have misunderstood the question. Why do you need a toolbar to add the calculate button. is there any problem placing a calculate button on the navigation bar (right hand corner). Do you need to complaicate by adding containerview? Also you won't need a segue.

Comment: It is right, It is just one of my three other views I need to change. We need to innovate, I am aware it is little bit tricky, but maybe someone already did it or uses an other solution to fix the ToolBar. As a consequence, I could meet the specifications in term of UX. ;)

Comment: Ok, when you say "toolbar not fixed on the bottom" is it partial hidden or does it appear in the center?

Comment: It appears in the at the end of the last static cells of the tableviewController. And it is not fixed, it scrolls with the rest of the tableview cells