# Xamarin for VS Table View cells not displaying label text

Tags: c#, xamarin-studio

I have a Table View embedded in a View Controller on my storyboard.  There are 3 Table View Cells in the Table View.  Each cell has one character of text in it: "A", "B" and "C".  The characters are visible on my screen in Visual Studio but when I run the app in the simulator, I see nothing.  I've double checked that the table/cells are enabled.  Storeboard XML below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="6211" systemVersion="14A298i" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" initialViewController="BYZ-38-t0r">
    <dependencies>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="6204"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="tne-QT-ifu">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="BYZ-38-t0r" customClass="ViewController" customModuleProvider="" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <layoutGuides>
                        <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="top" id="y3c-jy-aDJ"/>
                        <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="bottom" id="wfy-db-euE"/>
                    </layoutGuides>
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="8bC-Xf-vdC">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="600" height="600"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <containerView contentMode="scaleToFill" id="5" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" fixedFrame="YES">
                                <rect key="frame" x="116" y="126" width="320" height="300"/>
                                <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                                <connections>
                                    <segue id="66" destination="13" kind="embed"/>
                                </connections>
                            </containerView>
                        </subviews>
                    </view>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="dkx-z0-nzr" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="0.0" y="0.0"/>
        </scene>
        <scene sceneID="12">
            <objects>
                <tableViewController id="13" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <tableView key="view" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" clearsContextBeforeDrawing="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" alwaysBounceVertical="YES" dataMode="prototypes" style="plain" separatorStyle="default" rowHeight="44" sectionHeaderHeight="22" sectionFooterHeight="22" id="14">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="320" height="300"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                        <prototypes>
                            <tableViewCell contentMode="scaleToFill" selectionStyle="blue" hidesAccessoryWhenEditing="NO" indentationLevel="1" indentationWidth="0.0" id="17" rowHeight="44">
                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="22" width="320" height="44"/>
                                <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                <tableViewCellContentView key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" tableViewCell="17" id="18">
                                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="320" height="43.5"/>
                                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                </tableViewCellContentView>
                            </tableViewCell>
                            <tableViewCell contentMode="scaleToFill" selectionStyle="default" indentationWidth="10" id="72" rowHeight="44" indentationLevel="0" style="IBUITableViewCellStyleDefault" textLabel="76">
                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="66" width="320" height="44"/>
                                <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                <tableViewCellContentView key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" tableViewCell="72" id="73">
                                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="320" height="43.5"/>
                                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                    <subviews>
                                        <label opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="left" text="A" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" id="76">
                                            <rect key="frame" x="16" y="0.0" width="288" height="43.5"/>
                                            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                            <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="18"/>
                                            <color key="textColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="darkTextColor"/>
                                            <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                        </label>
                                    </subviews>
                                </tableViewCellContentView>
                            </tableViewCell>
                            <tableViewCell contentMode="scaleToFill" selectionStyle="default" indentationWidth="10" id="77" rowHeight="44" style="IBUITableViewCellStyleDefault" textLabel="81">
                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="110" width="320" height="44"/>
                                <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                <tableViewCellContentView key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" tableViewCell="77" id="78">
                                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="320" height="43.5"/>
                                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                    <subviews>
                                        <label opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="left" text="B" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" id="81">
                                            <rect key="frame" x="16" y="0.0" width="288" height="43.5"/>
                                            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                            <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="18"/>
                                            <color key="textColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="darkTextColor"/>
                                            <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                        </label>
                                    </subviews>
                                </tableViewCellContentView>
                            </tableViewCell>
                            <tableViewCell contentMode="scaleToFill" selectionStyle="default" indentationWidth="10" id="79" rowHeight="44" style="IBUITableViewCellStyleDefault" textLabel="82">
                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="154" width="320" height="44"/>
                                <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                <tableViewCellContentView key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" tableViewCell="79" id="80">
                                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="320" height="43.5"/>
                                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                    <subviews>
                                        <label opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="left" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" id="82" text="C">
                                            <rect key="frame" x="16" y="0.0" width="288" height="43.5"/>
                                            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                            <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="18"/>
                                            <color key="textColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="darkTextColor"/>
                                            <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                        </label>
                                    </subviews>
                                </tableViewCellContentView>
                            </tableViewCell>
                        </prototypes>
                        <connections>
                            <outlet property="dataSource" destination="13" id="15"/>
                            <outlet property="delegate" destination="13" id="16"/>
                        </connections>
                    </tableView>
                </tableViewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="19" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="646" y="-5"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
</document>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Static table view outside UITableViewController](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22364230/static-table-view-outside-uitableviewcontroller)

Answer (score 0):

The answer can be found in the link below.  Although the discussion in that link is for Xcode, the solution is the same.  Create a Table View Controller.  Add a Container View to your View Controller and embed the Table View Controller in that.  Change the Table View content to "Static Cells" then add a section.  From there you can edit your simple table that should have taken one step but somehow took 5!

Xamarin should remove the ability to add text too labels in cells that belong to a non-static cell content table.  It's just confusing.

[Static table view outside UITableViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22364230/static-table-view-outside-uitableviewcontroller)