# How to use a static UITableView inside a UIViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I know that it is not possible to add a static `UITableView` inside an `UIViewController` (or at least I could not find any way to do it). Trying to do a workaround (as pointed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22364230/static-table-view-outside-uitableviewcontroller#answer-25193002)), I am following these steps:

- I have created an `UIViewController` on my `Main.storyboard`.
- I have drag an `UIContainerView` inside my `UIViewController`.
- I have deleted the `UIViewController` embedded by default on my `UIContainerView`.
- I have created an `UITableViewController` and drag it to the `UIContainerView`.
- I have added a label with the text "Hello" into my `UITableViewCell`.

Here is the structure of this part on my `Main.storyboard`:

[image]

And here is the result that I am getting:

[image]

I can only get an empty `UITableView` without any information inside of it.

Am I missing something? Am I doing it in the wrong way?

**P.S:** I am using `Xcode8` and `Swift3`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using the datasource methods of the tableviewcontroller in code? Because if `numberOfRowsForIndexPath` returns 0, no tableviewcell will be loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a `UITableView` with **Prototype Cells** which is visible because in the grey area it's written "Prototype Content".

Change to **Static Cells** in the Table View inspector (on the right of the window) after selecting the **TableView** in **Interface Builder**.

[image: TableView inspector]
[image: Change to Static Cells]

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I am getting the data on my UITableView :)