# Add UIView to UITableViewController with Storyboards

Tags: ios, interface-builder, uistoryboard

On my app, I need to add a UIView to my UITableViewController. Right now, it's only letting me add it to the existing table view. What I want is to add it the UIView to my UITableViewController. Could someone help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: In a UITableViewController, the UITableView is the root view, so there is no "outside the tableview" where you can add another view

Comment: Could you explain it with more details, could you provide some drawing?

Comment: `UITableViewController` is a subclass of `UIViewController`. A view controller has a `view` property which is the root view. You can add subviews to this view but you can't add views above it since it is the root. In a UITableViewController, the tableview is the root view, so you can only add views to the tableview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use UIViewController, then you will be able to add the UITableView and UIView . If you use the UITableViewController, you can't add UIView in it

Comment: I need to use static cells, though.

Comment: You can use Container view inside your UIViewController
see this answer  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22364230/static-table-view-outside-uitableviewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

you can do this task with programmatically.

add this code in `viewDidLoad()` method:

```
func setupBottomView() {
    bottomView = BottomView(frame: .zero)

    view.addSubview(bottomView)

    bottomView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    // Constraint Layout
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        bottomView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0),
        bottomView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0),
        bottomView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0),
        bottomView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120)
        ])

}
```